# Can I transpose (Pivot) a table using a 'where' clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I need to create a pivot table from an original table in mysql, but I need to be specific about which rows i want to take the data into the new table i'm making.
I would be guessing i could use the 'where' clause in a query to create the pivot table, but i dont know exactly how. I have a code that allows me to create a pivot table from its original. It selects two rows, one for each 'max' function and turns them into columns.

```
create table `transp_table` as
select * from (
    select original_table,
    max(case when ID = 1.01 then value else 0 end) '1.01',
    max(case when ID = 1.02 then value else 0 end) '1.02'
    from(
    select ID, `month_1` value, 1 descrip 
    from disp
    union all
    select ID, `month_2` value, 2 descrip
    from disp
    union all
    select ID, `month_3` value, 3 descrip
    from disp
    union all
    select ID, `month_4` value, 4 descrip 
    from disp
    union all
    select ID, `month_5` value, 5 descrip 
    from disp
    union all
    select ID, `month_6` value, 6 descrip 
    from disp
    union all
    select ID, `month_7` value, 7 descrip 
    from disp
    union all
    select ID, `month_8` value, 8 descrip 
    from original_table
    ) src
    group by descrip
) as `transp_table`;
```

It works well to creating a pivot table, but for this model, i need to include a 'max' function for each specific `ID`. And from the original_table, there is a lot of rows. And there is, for an instance, a column in the original_table called 'type_of_product', and i need to select the rows that have a specific string in it. Is there a query were i could select the rows to make the pivot table without having to type for each one of them like in the example above? Here's the structure with a sample of the original_table:

```
CREATE TABLE original_table (
  `ID` float not null, `type_of_product` text, `month_1` int, 
    `month_2` int, `month_3` int, `month_4` int, `month_5` int, `month_6` int)

INSERT INTO `original_table` (
 ID, type_of_procduct, `month-1`, `month_2`, `month_3`, `month_4`, `month_5`, `month_6`)
 VALUES 

(1.01, 'TV', 50, 53, 20, 33, 134, 0),

(1.02, 'DVD', 36, 12, 5, 0, 0, 26),

(2.01, 'DVD', 11, 12, 30, 5, 22, 0),

(3.01, 'CD', 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 19),

(3.02, 'TV', 3, 6, 0, 0, 10, 15),

(3.03, 'TV', 500, 20, 0, 0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Your schema clearly violates the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of 
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) so writing any queries on this table is going to be a nightmare. Can you restructure the schema?

Comment: What is `select original_table` supposed to mean? The parameters to `select` must be column names or expressions, `original_table` is a table name, not a column name. Did you mean `original_table.*`?

Comment: What is a "transpost table"? I googled and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Are you talking about a "pivot table"?

Comment: Its turning specific columns from a table into rows

Comment: "Can you restructure the schema?"
What exactly you mean? The data in the months columns are supposed to have either NULL, or an integer number from 0 to a few hundreds.